# Smallest Xwindow for Linux

Tags: linux, gnome, kde-plasma, xfce

What is the smallest, friendliest **Window Manager** that I can run on Linux.
I currently use Gnome which is a bit heavy.

All I would be needing it for is to run Firefox.

Xfce?

Comment: Maybe he wants to write one himself.

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser, but until then...

Comment: @balpha -- It's a bit of a reach, but programmers *do* spend all day immersed in their screen/desktop environment.  I'd give the benefit of the doubt and not downvote it.

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs to SO (by the way, I use xmonad, it's simple, lightweight and stable)

Comment: @Geoff Fritz: I don't think "belongs-on-whatnot" is *ever* a reason for downvoting.

Comment: @VN4CA: Your terminology is confused... Gnome is not an X server, does not provide an X server, and several of its components don't even depend on an X server.

Comment: gnome is desktop environment, not a x server nor a window manager

Answer (score 5):

try a [tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager) like [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) or [ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/)

Comment: Don't forget Awesome ;) http://awesome.naquadah.org/download/

Comment: +1 for mentioning XMonad

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean manager?  Anyway, I use a little gem called "evilwm".  Takes some getting used to, but it has the smallest memory footprint of any WM I know of, and the single-pixel window borders w/o decorations yields tons of screen real estate, which I use mostly for xterms anyway.

I launch firefox by way of a shell alias, rather than rely on menus icons.  Works great!

Comment: +1 for correction about the window manager. Never heard of evilwm, but I've generally used Fluxbox...or Ratpoison.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Awesome Window Manager](http://awesome.naquadah.org/). It's a lightweight tiling window manager. After learning the hotkeys, it can become a very productive environment.

Comment: +100 AWM *is* Awesome. In http://awesome.naquadah.org/download/ you'll find packages for a lot of different distros.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's a tiling window manager: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling%5Fwindow%5Fmanager

Answer (score 1):

Gnome is not an Xserver, but a (set of) X client programs. The X server that both you and I are running most likely is X.org.

On top of the X server, you typically have several client programs. The smallest X setup is when you just run an xterm. Invoke "xinit" on a Linux console to find out how that looks like.

A sole xterm is fairly unfriendly, so you typically also use a Window manager. The smallest window manager might be wm2; see http://xwinman.org/ for a list of options. It seems that Blackbox is also fairly small.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a terminology problem here.

- Gnome is a X desktop environment. It includes a variety of interaction support libraries, a file manager and importantly:
- A window manager --- which puts decoration on windows, deals with moving, hiding, expanding etc. them

They both run on top of the **X server**, which really only provides the graphical environment and abstracts the input devices.

So, do you want a minimal desktop environment (XFCE?), and bare minimal windowmanager (TWM?), or a small X server?

Comment: I need to run Firfox on a think server. Whatever it take to run Firfox, but I don't want Gnome or KDE. So, I guess Window Manager is the term.

Comment: Ah so. Follow the links other have given to pick a decent lightweight window manager. There are plenty to choose from. I've used flwm and blackbox with some success.

Answer (score 0):

xfce runs much smaller than gnome and is full featured. If you want to go a bit more spartan I'd suggest fluxbox, but there's lots of other choices.

[Here's](http://xwinman.org/) a list of lots of choices, basically anything that's not KDE or Gnome will be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

smallest is probably xfce, most friendly is entirely subjective

Answer (score 0):

I always liked  [FluxBox](http://www.fluxbox.org) It's lite, it's quick and it's easy to setup :)

Answer (score 0):

I too think you're asking for desktop environments (like KDE, Gnome, FluxBox, etc), or at least window managers (kwin, metacity, tvwm, twm, etc) and not X servers.  If so, FluxBox, xfce or even tvwm might be your best choice.

But.... if you really want to go lower, first replace X.org with [KDrive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDrive).  It's the one used by [DSL (Damn Small Linux)](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) and it's much lighter; mostly because it has very few drivers, mainly using [directfb](http://www.directfb.org/) API.

Or, you can also skip X completely, and use FF on top of just directfb.  [here](http://www.directfb.org/wiki/index.php/DFBMozilla)'s an old proof of concept patch, and a [more recent discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.builds/browse_thread/thread/81b79f8e833314eb).  (disclaimer, i haven't tried any of these)

Comment: Window Manager is what I am looking for. I like to run a thin Linux server that can also run Firefox without the need of pulling in Gnome.